# Need my random effects to show the full line

Tags: bash, scripts

I am working on a script for random predictions and unfortunately instead of the script taking the full lines from the two random lists (Things and Effects) it prints a random word from each. Can someone show me how to have the script print the full line from the two lists. Below is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Random lists picks
# This is a script for picking random choices as a prediction.


Things="Walk
Song
Talk
Friend
Spontaneous act
Call"

Effects="will bless you
will lift your spirit
is healthy
can help
will touch you
will make you smile
is what what you need
makes a difference in your life
can add comfort
isn't necessarily without virtue
adds something to your day"



things=($Things)
effects=($Effects)

num_things=${#things[*]}
num_effects=${#effects[*]}

echo -n " A ${things[$((RANDOM%num_things))]} "
echo ${effects[$((RANDOM%num_effects))]}
```

Comment: I suggest that you use `echo` to print intermediate results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `IFS` (Internal Field Separator) variable of `bash` to newline `\n` while creating array out of the variable so that each newline separated entry of the variable will be taken as an array element. In your primary script the array is being created out of the entries of variable separated on the default `IFS` value i.e. space, tab and newline.

In a nutshell, you need to change those two array declaration lines to:

```
IFS=$'\n' things=( $Things )
IFS=$'\n' effects=( $Effects )
```

So, your final script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Random lists picks
# This is a script for picking random choices as a prediction.


Things="Walk
Song
Talk
Friend
Spontaneous act
Call"

Effects="will bless you
will lift your spirit
is healthy
can help
will touch you
will make you smile
is what what you need
makes a difference in your life
can add comfort
isn't necessarily without virtue
adds something to your day"



IFS=$'\n' things=( $Things )
IFS=$'\n' effects=( $Effects )

num_things=${#things[*]}
num_effects=${#effects[*]}

echo -n "A ${things[$((RANDOM%num_things))]} "
echo "${effects[$((RANDOM%num_effects))]}"
```

Comment: Once again you come through with the answer Heemayl ! Thank you my friend!!

Comment: @HankG: You are most welcome..Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you had a little misunderstanding with the use of arrays.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Random lists picks
# This is a script for picking random choices as a prediction.

# Create array "things"
things=('Walk'
'Song'
'Talk'
'Friend'
'Spontaneous act'
'Call')

# Create array "effects"
effects=('will bless you'
'will lift your spirit'
'is healthy'
'can help'
'will touch you'
'will make you smile'
'is what what you need'
'makes a difference in your life'
'can add comfort'
"isn't necessarily without virtue"
'adds something to your day')

# Place the array size
num_things=${#things[@]}
num_effects=${#effects[@]}

echo -n " A ${things[$((RANDOM%num_things))]} "
echo "${effects[$((RANDOM%num_effects))]}"
```

Comment: I will definitely take this advice to heart, thank you A.B.!